# How to block a person from typing user input in Java during Thread.sleep

Tags: java, thread-sleep

So, in this code, the main method keeps on repeating itself. I know the reason why, but I don't know how to fix it.

To be specific, the thing that's happening is that there's a `Thread.sleep`after the answer has been given(I'm making a calculator, so the answer could be like "sum: 4") and the user can spam within the `Thread.sleep`. The program thinks their still trying to type a type of math question(because you type addition, subtraction, or multiplication) and then it repeats the main question twice.

Here's the addition method:

```
private static void Addition() {

    Scanner inputa = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("How many numbers would you like to add?");
    int outputa = inputa.nextInt();

    int sum = 0;
    for(int countera = 0; countera < outputa; countera++) {

        try  {
            System.out.println("Number " + (countera + 1) + ":");

            sum += inputa.nextInt();
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ex) {

            System.out.println("Not a valid integer.");

            try {

                Thread.sleep(2000);

            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {

                System.out.println("Error occured.");

            }

            String[] args = {};
            MiriMain.main(args);

        }

    }

    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);

    try {

        Thread.sleep(2500);

    }
    catch(InterruptedException Ex) {

        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

    }

    String[] args = {};
    MiriMain.main(args);//MiriMain is the main method

}
```

So within the sleep, the user can still type. How can I block the person from typing when the `Thread.sleep` is still activated? Any answer is helpful.

Thanks.

---

`

Comment: It's not possible to disable the console using standard libraries.

Comment: I think you're trying to solve the wrong problem here... There is a bug in your code that make it repeat itself. Fix the bug, stop worrying about keyboard input during thread.sleep.

Comment: Aside from that, why are you sleeping at all? Just calculate and display the result.

Comment: I'm sleeping because I want the main method to display after the result has been shown.